# How to make sense of rearranging summation symbols in Sheldon Axler's Matrix Multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation-method

I am reading Sheldon Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right, Third Edition". I am looking at the page where he defines matrix multiplication. He shows the motivation behind the way it is defined, as a composition of Linear Maps.  I intuitively understand it; to show the effect U1 has on W1 you use T to impress U1 on the basis vectors of V, and then you use S to impress the combination of the basis vectors of V onto W1.  So I have no problem actually performing the matrix multiplication, and I have no problem understanding it intuitively. But I have one issue understanding his derivation of it.

[This is the excerpt from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMe0H.png)

How does he get from the third line to the fourth line? I don't understand the rules of shifting around summation symbols. he shifted the order of the scalars and of the summation symbols.

Comment: Not an answer, but his [fourth edition](https://linear.axler.net/) has just come out. I'm very fond of his book, maybe you can try this new edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
 \sum_{r=1}^{n}C_{r,k}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{m}A_{j,r}w_j\right)&=\nonumber\\
 =&\sum_{r=1}^{n}C_{r,k}\left(A_{1,r}w_1+\cdots+A_{m,r}w_m\right)\nonumber \\
 =&C_{1,k}\left(A_{1,1}w_1+\cdots+A_{m,1}w_m\right)+\cdots+C_{n,k}\left(A_{1,n}w_1+\cdots+A_{m,n}w_m\right)\nonumber\\
 =&\left(A_{1,1}C_{1,k}w_1+\cdots+A_{m,1}C_{1,k}w_m\right)+\cdots+\left(A_{1,n}C_{n,k}w_1+\cdots+A_{m,n}C_{n,k}w_m\right)\nonumber\\
 =&\left(A_{1,1}C_{1,k}w_1+\cdots+A_{1,n}C_{n,k}w_1\right)+\cdots+\left(A_{m,1}C_{1,k}w_m+\cdots+A_{m,n}C_{n,k}w_m\right)\nonumber\\
 =&\left(A_{1,1}C_{1,k}+\cdots+A_{1,n}C_{n,k}\right)w_1+\cdots+\left(A_{m,1}C_{1,k}+\cdots+A_{m,n}C_{n,k}\right)w_m\nonumber\\
 =&\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}A_{1,r}C_{r,k}\right)w_1+\cdots+\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}A_{m,r}C_{r,k}\right)w_m\nonumber\\
 =&\sum_{j=1}^{m}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}A_{j,r}C_{r,k}\right)w_j 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much. Even though I knew this to be true I had trouble explicitly spelling it out like you did, this was driving me crazy for about 6 hours, you just made my day